# connecting three QGraphicsRectItems into one object

Tags: c++, qt

I am walking my way through a beginner (non-class based) project using Qt and c++. The main goal of the project is to learn design patterns. But before I get to learn how to use and implement different design patterns in order to improve the code, I have to have a working implementation without any design pattern first! I want to design and implement an object that is composed of one large rectangle along with two smaller rectangles, each connected to the upper right and the upper left corners of the main rectangle. Assume the main rectangle is a player's body and the two smaller rectangles represent the right and the left arms of the player. The current code allows me to initialize the large rectangle and move it to the left or to the right using the keyboard.

Here is my starting .h:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H


#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QDebug>



class Player : public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem{
    Q_OBJECT //Macro


public:
    Player();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event);

};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

and this is the .cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"


Player::Player(){
    setRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    //setBrush(Qt::black); //error: reference to type 'const QBrush' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'Qt::GlobalColor' setBrush(Qt::black);
}


void Player::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    //qDebug() << "Player knows you pressed a buton";
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Left){
        if(pos().x() > 0)
            setPos(x()-50, y());
    } else if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Right){
        if(pos().x() + rect().width() < 1200)
            setPos(x()+50, y());
    }
}
```

and this the main function:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QTimer>
#include <Player.h>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QColor>
#include <QKeyEvent>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //has a session
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();;
    //has a view
    QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(scene);;
    //has a player
    Player * player = new Player();;


    //Add player to a session
    scene -> addItem(player);


    //Make player focusable
    player->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    player->setFocus();


    //set coordinates
    view->setFixedSize(1200, 600);
    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 1200, 600);
    player->setPos(view->width()/2-((player->rect().width())/2), view->height()-player->rect().height());

    // a view is invisible by default, you have to show it
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I have a few questions that I would appreciate any help or any hints with.

1) Whenever I try to set the color using setBrush within the player's class, I get an error (shown above in the .cpp file next to the (setBrush(Qt::black)) line. However, if I implement the same line within the main function, it works. Any idea why this is the case? I still prefer to set the color within the class rather than in the main function, any way as of how to do this?

2) Composition can give me the ability to initialize multiple rectangles within the player's class. However, If I try to use composition rather than inheritance, I lose the ability to move in the player's main rectangle! is there any explanation for this? how can I maintain the ability to move the player using composition rather than inheritance? here is the code with composition.

.h:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H


#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QDebug>



class Player : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT //Macro!

public:
    QGraphicsRectItem * curRect;
    Player();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event);

};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

.cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(){
    curRect = new QGraphicsRectItem;
    curRect->setRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    //setBrush(Qt::black); //error: reference to type 'const QBrush' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'Qt::GlobalColor' setBrush(Qt::black);
}


void Player::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    //qDebug() << "Player knows you pressed a buton";
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Left){
        if(curRect->pos().x() > 0)
            curRect->setPos(curRect->x()-50, curRect->y());
    } else if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Right){
        if(curRect->pos().x() + curRect->rect().width() < 1200)
            curRect->setPos(curRect->x()+50, curRect->y());
    }
}
```

main:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QTimer>
#include <Player.h>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QColor>
#include <QKeyEvent>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //has a session
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();;
    //has a view
    QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(scene);;
    //has a player
    Player * player = new Player();;


    //Add player to a session, set its initial position and color
    scene -> addItem(player->curRect);


    //Make player focusable
    player->curRect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    player->curRect->setFocus();


    //set coordinates
    view->setFixedSize(1200, 600);
    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 1200, 600);
    player->curRect->setPos(view->width()/2-((player->curRect->rect().width())/2), view->height()-player->curRect->rect().height());

    // a view is invisible by default, you have to show it
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

3) Assuming there is a way to use composition and allow moving the player's main rectangle (curRect), I can easily add two more rectangles and set their positions accordingly. The main challenge however is, how can I connect the three rectangles to present one rather than three components? I need the three of them to move together.

I really appreciate any feedback or directions. QT is fun and I hope to be able to learn more about its capabilities.

Best,

Comment: QGraphicsItemGroup might be the composition-mechanism you are looking for:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitemgroup.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint, any idea why I have issues related to question 1 and question 2 above?

Comment: I'm not sure why setBrush(Qt::black) doesn't work, but I think setBrush(QColor(Qt::black)) will probably work.  The other question I don't really understand, it's not clear what you mean by "the ability to move".

Comment: By thr ability to move I meant that the player is responsive to keyboard events, specifically the leftarrow and the rightarrow keys!

Comment: If by "use composition" you mean you are adding multiple items to the QGraphicsScene, perhaps the keyPressEvent() calls are being called on one of the other objects instead of your Player object?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience in qt libraries but it seems that in  "QGraphicsItem" library which you use in your "Player.h" the setbrush is defined as:

```
void setBrush(const QBrush &brush)
```

But in some other libraries such as "QPen", this function is overloaded as below:

```
void QPainter::setBrush ( const QColor & color )
```

see : http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpen.html

Thus maybe in your main, qt files you have included  have overloaded version of the setBrush that can accept (const QColor) as argument.

Comment: Thanks Kamyar, I needed to include Painter in Player.h in order to get the setBrush working.